# How to reenable Google Analytics for OneTrust?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, one-trust

Testing around with OneTrust functions on my application I used OneTrust.BlockGoogleAnalytics() and now I can not see the data layer pushs on the GTM/GA Debugger extension.

Where, how do I revert this command? I expected to be able to give false to the function, but that don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just clear your cookies and local storage.

But it shouldn't block your datalayer pushes. That's a bit too much to expect from one trust. Maybe you're mixing up DL pushes with actual events sent.

Also, one trust gives [documentation](https://community.cookiepro.com/s/article/UUID-d8291f61-aa31-813a-ef16-3f6dec73d643?language=en_US) on how to use that function. It seems like the function accepts two args. I'm not sure if it works with no args, but the documentation still specifies how to check the state of certain trackers to see if they're blocked or not. That part seems to be broken in their documentation, but it's easy to decipher what they meant by `window['ga-disable-${gaID}'`